# What happens when I estimate too many univariate relationships?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, estimation

Suppose we are in the context of OLS regression, and we have $n$ data points. If I run multivariate regression I can only estimate $n$ coefficients (including the intercept), and at that point the variance of the estimates will be very large because I only have $1$ data point per coefficient.

However in simple regression I can estimate as many coefficients as I want by running one regression per variable. So if $k$ is the number of single-variable regressions, each with a different variable, what happens when $k \gg n$?

I'm not talking about doing hypothesis testing, where the false positive rates blows up, but from an estimation standpoint. It feels like there should still be some price to pay considering how the multivariate case only supports $n$ variables.